# Flag dates based on multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df, this provides information about the create_date and delete_date(if any) for a given ID.

**Structure:**

```
ID create_date1 create_date2 delete_date1  delete_date2
1  01-01-2014   NA           NA            NA    
2  01-04-2014   01-08-2014   01-05-2014    NA
```

- the create_date and delete_date extends till 10, i.e. create_date10
  and delete_date10 columns are present

**Rules/Logic:**

- We charge a user on monthly basis, if a user was created on 30th of a month, even then it's treated as if the user was active for a month(very low cost)
- If a user has a delete date (irrespective on which date) in this month, then from next month the user is not charged
- If a user has only create_date and no delete_date then all dates including the create_month is charged

**Output expected:**

```
ID 2014-01 2014-02 2014-03 2014-04 2014-05 2014-06 2014-07 2014-08
1  1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
2  0       0       0       1       1       0       0       1
```

- so on till current date
- 1 indicates the user is charged/active for that month

**Problem:**

I have been struggling to do this, but can't even understand how to do this. My earlier method is a bit too slow

**Previous Solution:**

1. Make the dataset into tall
2. Insert sequence of dates for each ID as a new column
3. Use a for loop to check the status
4. for each ID, status is equal to 1,
5. if create_date is equal to sequence, and it's 0 if the lag(delete_date) is equal to sequence
6. else is same as lag(status)

   ```
   ID create_date  delete_date sequence  status?
   1  01-01-2014   NA          2014-01   1
   1  01-01-2014   NA          2014-02   1
   1  01-01-2014   NA          2014-03   1
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may not be that efficient : assuming this is just for a single year(could be extended easily)

```
# convert all dates to Date format
df[,colnames(df[-1])] = lapply(colnames(df[-1]), function(x) as.Date(df[[x]], format = "%d-%m-%Y"))
# extract the month
library(lubridate)
df[,colnames(df[-1])] = lapply(colnames(df[-1]), function(x) month(df[[x]]))
# df
#  ID create_date1 create_date2 delete_date1 delete_date2
#1  1            1           NA           NA           NA
#2  2            4            8            5           NA

# get the current month 
current.month <- month(Sys.Date())
# assume for now current month is 9
current.month <- 9

flags <- rep(FALSE, current.month)

func <- function(x){
  x[is.na(x)] <- current.month     # replacing all NA with current month(9)
  create.columns.indices <- x[grepl("create_date", colnames(df[-1]))] # extract the create_months
  delete.columns.indices <- x[grepl("delete_date", colnames(df[-1]))] # extract the delete_months
  flags <- pmin(1,colSums(t(sapply(seq_along(create.columns.indices), 
                            function(x){
                                         flags[create.columns.indices[x]:delete.columns.indices[x]] = TRUE;
                                         flags
                                        }))))
  flags
}
df1 = cbind(df$ID , t(apply(df[-1], 1, func)))
colnames(df1) = c("ID", paste0("month",1:current.month))
# df1
#     ID month1 month2 month3 month4 month5 month6 month7 month8 month9
#[1,]  1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
#[2,]  2      0      0      0      1      1      0      0      1      1
```

Comment: @Liked the logic, will give it a try now

Comment: @user3875610 you will get a better picture of how `func` works with each row, by running `debug(func)`

Comment: Thanks for this, will wait for 5 mins in hope of better answer and then accept your answer!

Comment: yup sure, try yourself also.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a still-pretty-long tidyverse approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% gather(var, date, -ID) %>%    # reshape to long form
    # separate date type from column set number
    separate(var, c('action', 'number'), sep = '_date', convert = TRUE) %>% 
    mutate(date = as.Date(date, '%d-%m-%Y')) %>%    # parse dates
    spread(action, date) %>%    # spread create and delete to two columns
    mutate(min_date = min(create, delete, na.rm = TRUE),      # add helper columns; use outside
           max_date = max(create, delete, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%  # variable to save memory if an issue
    group_by(ID, number) %>% 
    mutate(month = list(seq(min_date, max_date, by = 'month')),    # add month sequence list column
           # boolean vector of whether range of months in whole range
           active = ifelse(is.na(create), 
                           list(rep(FALSE, length(month[[1]]))),
                           lapply(month, `%in%`, 
                                  seq.Date(create, 
                                           min(delete, max_date, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                           by = 'month')))) %>% 
    unnest() %>%    # unnest list columns to long form
    group_by(ID, month = format(month, '%Y-%m')) %>%
    summarise(active = any(active) * 1L) %>%     # combine muliple rows for one ID
    spread(month, active)    # reshape to wide form

## Source: local data frame [2 x 9]
## Groups: ID [2]
## 
##      ID `2014-01` `2014-02` `2014-03` `2014-04` `2014-05` `2014-06` `2014-07` `2014-08`
## * <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>
## 1     1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1
## 2     2         0         0         0         1         1         0         0         1
```

Comment: Longer and much more cleaner, will test this soon! Thanks a lot

Comment: how does you code account for current date and month, meaning the table must compute status for 2017-01?

Comment: It uses the maximum of all the dates as the maximum range. If you want to set it to the current date, use `max_date = Sys.Date()`. You may want to round dates to the first of the month, or consider using `zoo::yearmon` class instead.